# I can't install Psycopg2 with Python3 on Mac. I've installed Python3 and pip3

Tags: python, python-3.x, psycopg2

I've tried to type this command:
pip3 install --user psycopg2 psycopg2-binary

Bash answers:
ERROR: running install

```
It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.

You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
required for the build and try again.

For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
<http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/qf/kmd2_y0j2p9_10zkd5ctvm880000gn/T/pip-install-i0kg4ysj/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/qf/kmd2_y0j2p9_10zkd5ctvm880000gn/T/pip-record-lkzzuu55/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/qf/kmd2_y0j2p9_10zkd5ctvm880000gn/T/pip-install-i0kg4ysj/psycopg2/

Comment: does `pip3 install psycopg2` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not being able to install psycopg2 as the gcc compiler in your device is either outdated and not compatible to install and run it, or it does not exist.

if you just run `pip install psycopg2-binary`, then it will work on your development and testing environment, however it is not recommended for production.

To install psycopg2, make sure that you have gcc installed in your device by running-

`gcc --version
 gcc where`

If it is not installed, then install it by referring to the guide here-

[Installing GCC in Mac](https://www.mkyong.com/mac/how-to-install-gcc-compiler-on-mac-os-x/)

I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score -2):

after successfully installed python and pip, this command should work:
pip install psycopg2