# psycopg2 for python3? Mac wont install the wheel

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, psycopg2

Machine: Mac OSX
Python Version: 3.X, specifically 3.7.3

I was looking at the psycopg2 documentation, it said it was Python3 friendly.  https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/

It was saying that all i would need to do is to do something akin to: `pip install psycopg2` but when I do it, setup.py install will give an error.

> ERROR: Command "/usr/local/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/r3/lv90w0yx6xq9t2p4qgb7yb1r0000gn/T/pip-install-66v9kpqs/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/r3/lv90w0yx6xq9t2p4qgb7yb1r0000gn/T/pip-record-8anshmva/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/r3/lv90w0yx6xq9t2p4qgb7yb1r0000gn/T/pip-install-66v9kpqs/psycopg2/

I was trying to figure out how to progress with this, in order to have psycopg2 be easily used within Python3.

I dont think i should be downloading the source and building it and likewise their website says I shouldnt use binaries for production.

The following gives the insight to use the binary on my mac, but not to use it for production.  [I can't install Psycopg2 with Python3 on Mac. I've installed Python3 and pip3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56275454/i-cant-install-psycopg2-with-python3-on-mac-ive-installed-python3-and-pip3) This gives me one caveat, I am not sure what my prod server will be.  Usually it is unix, but i was thinking "wait, does mac have a prod server? How would i do it for there then?"

It wanted me to just implement: `pip3 install psycopg2-binary` but like what the psycopg2 website said, that should not be a prod solution.  Me personally, I dont like writing custom scripts for custom OS.  I think that to give the best experience, the application should be cross-platform compatible, ESPECIALLY since this is python.

I cant seem to figure it out, has anyone figured out how to do this?

***EDIT:*** Pip3 install seems to cause an error with GCC when compiling.  The issue I saw was as follows:

> ```
> ld: library not found for -lssl
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
> ```

I tested it and gcc is in my path, so it seems that it doesnt know what lssl is.  why would that not be a valid statement.  I figured pip3 would have tested against this?

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the error with a mac book running on OSX 10.13.6, python 3.7.2. I did pip install psycopg2 and the installation was successful.

Comment: Why would using pip3 not be a "prod solution"?

Comment: no, its not the use of pip3 vs pip, as much as using the `psycopg2-binary`.  That is weird that you got it to work.  I am on 10.14.5.  I am going to edit the question with the error log

Comment: `ld: library not found for -lssl` -> `brew install openssl`. There's nothing wrong with Python, you're missing libraries to compile C extensions in the `psycopg2` package.

Comment: odd.  I did `brew install openssl` and it said it was already installed.

Comment: Then you have an issue with your current MacOS version and Homebrew, most probably due to an upgrade from High Sierra to Mojave; [Linking not working in homebrew's cmake since Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54068035/linking-not-working-in-homebrews-cmake-since-mojave) might be helpful to start with. I'd say XY problem, not related to Python...

Comment: Esp. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57014480/2650249) in the question should provide you with some helpful info. I don't work with MacOS since Mojave anymore so can't say for sure whether a perm change is a good idea, but the flag adjustment looks promising, smth like `LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib" pip install psycopg2 --no-binary=psycopg2`